# Change column data into column names

Tags: r

I have a data frame that looks like this

```
       Date    Score
A       1-1      5
A       1-2      6
A       1-3      2
A       1-4      9
A       1-5      4
B       1-1      3
B       1-2      6
C       1-1      7
C       1-2      2
C       1-3      5
```

I want to change my column names so that they show the date and rename them t1, t2, t3 etc. The new data frame should look like this:

```
       t1    t2    t3    t4    t5    
A      5      6     2     9     4
B      3      6
C      7      2     5
```

Data

```
dput(head(comp_temp,20))
structure(list(Name = c("A", "A", "A", "A", 
"A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", 
"A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", 
"A", "A"), `Date time` = c("03/01/2020", "03/02/2020", 
"03/03/2020", "03/04/2020", "03/05/2020", "03/06/2020", "03/07/2020", 
"03/08/2020", "03/09/2020", "03/10/2020", "03/11/2020", "03/12/2020", 
"03/13/2020", "03/14/2020", "03/15/2020", "03/16/2020", "03/17/2020", 
"03/18/2020", "03/19/2020", "03/20/2020"), Score = c(35.4, 
36.5, 34.7, 34.2, 32.1, 25.5, 27, 32, 34.9, 33.5, 29.4, 22.3, 
23.8, 29.9, 33.5, 33.4, 33.9, 33.7, 40.3, 37.1)), row.names = c(NA, 
-20L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Comment: On Stack Overflow it's always appreciated if you show some own effort. Not only because it makes clear what you tried and, hence, where you need help, but also because it usually clarifies more about what you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this `dplyr` and `tidyr` approach. You can separate the `Date` variable in order to map the values for headers and then use `pivot_wider()`. Here the code:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
#Code
df %>% separate(Date,c('V1','V2')) %>%
  mutate(V2=paste0('t',V2)) %>%
  pivot_wider(names_from = V2,values_from=Score) %>% select(-V1)
```

Output:

```
# A tibble: 1 x 6
  Var      t1    t2    t3    t4    t5
  <chr> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int>
1 A         5     6     2     9     4
```

Some data used:

```
#Data
df <- structure(list(Var = c("A", "A", "A", "A", "A"), Date = c("1-1", 
"1-2", "1-3", "1-4", "1-5"), Score = c(5L, 6L, 2L, 9L, 4L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-5L))
```

**Update:** Try this approach for the data you shared. I have mixed data with new values so that you can see how the output is produced:

```
#Code 2
mdf2 <- mdf %>%
  #First mutate date to similar format
  mutate(`Date time`=as.Date(`Date time`,'%m/%d/%Y'),
         Date=paste0('T',format(`Date time`,'%d'))) %>% select(-`Date time`) %>%
  #Reshape
  pivot_wider(names_from = Date,values_from=Score)
```

Output:

```
# A tibble: 2 x 21
  Name    T01   T02   T03   T04   T05   T06   T07   T08   T09   T10   T11   T12   T13   T14
  <chr> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
1 A      35.4  36.5  34.7  34.2  32.1  25.5    27    32  34.9  33.5  29.4  22.3  23.8  29.9
2 B      35.4  36.5  34.7  34.2  32.1  25.5    27    32  34.9  33.5  29.4  22.3  23.8  29.9
# ... with 6 more variables: T15 <dbl>, T16 <dbl>, T17 <dbl>, T18 <dbl>, T19 <dbl>, T20 <dbl>
```

New data used:

```
#Data
mdf <- structure(list(Name = c("A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", 
"A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "B", 
"B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", 
"B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B"), `Date time` = c("03/01/2020", 
"03/02/2020", "03/03/2020", "03/04/2020", "03/05/2020", "03/06/2020", 
"03/07/2020", "03/08/2020", "03/09/2020", "03/10/2020", "03/11/2020", 
"03/12/2020", "03/13/2020", "03/14/2020", "03/15/2020", "03/16/2020", 
"03/17/2020", "03/18/2020", "03/19/2020", "03/20/2020", "03/01/2020", 
"03/02/2020", "03/03/2020", "03/04/2020", "03/05/2020", "03/06/2020", 
"03/07/2020", "03/08/2020", "03/09/2020", "03/10/2020", "03/11/2020", 
"03/12/2020", "03/13/2020", "03/14/2020", "03/15/2020", "03/16/2020", 
"03/17/2020", "03/18/2020", "03/19/2020", "03/20/2020"), Score = c(35.4, 
36.5, 34.7, 34.2, 32.1, 25.5, 27, 32, 34.9, 33.5, 29.4, 22.3, 
23.8, 29.9, 33.5, 33.4, 33.9, 33.7, 40.3, 37.1, 35.4, 36.5, 34.7, 
34.2, 32.1, 25.5, 27, 32, 34.9, 33.5, 29.4, 22.3, 23.8, 29.9, 
33.5, 33.4, 33.9, 33.7, 40.3, 37.1)), row.names = c(NA, -40L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Comment: I'm getting the following error:
Error in UseMethod("pivot_wider") : 
  no applicable method for 'pivot_wider' applied to an object of class "c('double', 'numeric')"

Comment: @Rnovice Your data looks like having different formats. Try leaving the score variable as numeric and the Date variable as character! Let me know if that works!

Comment: Using head(), my Score data was <dbl>. 
This is the error message I'm getting now: Error in UseMethod("separate_") : 
  no applicable method for 'separate_' applied to an object of class "function"

Comment: @Rnovice Data issue, could your please use `dput(head(yourdataframe,20))` and paste the output in the question in order to help you? Let me know when you update the question with this new information!

Comment: Updated!
I should also mention that I have more than one row name (A, B, C etc..). I've updated the question regarding this as well

Comment: @Rnovice I have added an update for the answer. Please check and test with the new data I created for you. Let me know how that goes!

Comment: When I use View(), there doesn't seem to be any change in my table.

I'm assuming the following warnings are the be expected:
Warning message:
Values are not uniquely identified; output will contain list-cols.
* Use `values_fn = list` to suppress this warning.
* Use `values_fn = length` to identify where the duplicates arise
* Use `values_fn = {summary_fun}` to summarise duplicates

Comment: @Rnovice Please test with the code in the post first.

Answer (score 0):

`newdataframe= data.frame(t=t(df$Score),row.names = 'A')`

Comment: I have several other row names (and the dates repeat over the month of march). How do I create a new row for each name (A, B, C, D etc) containing daily scores with column names showing the date?